# Magento 2.4 getting wrong css & js path on frontend

Tags: url, static-content-deploy, magento2.4.2

I'm getting the wrong media, JS & CSS file path on the frontend and backend after installing Magento 2.4.2.
Please review the below URLs we are getting.
I've tried updating the value in the database core_config_data table, Also in-store configuration values.

[image]

Comment: Hi! Which part of the URL is invalid? Could you post full url path with `example.com` as domain mask?

Comment: Yes, Suppose the require js file url which I'm getting on frontend. 
 https://example.com/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/requirejs/require.js

Comment: What is your expected URL?

Comment: It should also include in baseURL/pub/static/..... currently it is not showing the pub folder before static folder

Comment: But could add to your question both URLs: correct one and current one?

It definitely shouldn't have `pub` directory inside URL, because `MAGE_ROOT/pub` should be your default root location in vhost config file (`root $MAGE_ROOT/pub;` if you use nginx).

Comment: @sourabhyadav have you check your frontend? Is that loading properly or not?

Comment: you need to put url in core_config like "https://example.com/pub/static/"

Answer (score 1):

You need to put url in core_config like "https://example.com/pub/static/"

it will help you

Comment: It will work, but `pub` should never be in path on correctly configured Magento instance.

Comment: then please remove value from that field. make it empty it will help you. dont forget to clear cache after that

Comment: Yes it was cache related error. it fixed automatically after cache was disabled